# Android: Notifcation wont show

Tags: android

I am working on a simple service in my app that also dispatches a notification to show the user, that the service is running. This DID work but stopped from one day to the other. I know that the code is beeing called right. I set a testing toast in within those lines and that is getting called every half second, so it should work but no notificaion shows up in the notification bar. Please have a look:

```
void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()
        {
            _notificationIsLive = true;

            RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.Notification);
            contentView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.txt_crrentSong_notification, Activity_Player.txt_CurrentSong.Text);
            contentView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.txt_crrentSong__artist_notification, Activity_Player.txt_CurrentArtist.Text);

            notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);

            Task.Delay(_countDownFirstRound).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                notificationBuilder
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.btn_icon_header)
                .SetCustomContentView(contentView);

                var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                notificationManager.Notify(50, notificationBuilder.Build());

                DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning();//This is for repeate every 1s.

                _countDownFirstRound = 50;

                // Click on notification, and return to app. Only works, because _2TimerRunning is set as : "LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance"
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_Player));
                notificationIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionMain);
                notificationIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                notificationBuilder.SetContentIntent(contentIntent);

            }, 

            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you aware off the notifications changes to Android 8?

Comment: please elaborate ...

Comment: On which Android version it does not work for you?

Comment: Okay so I just found out that changing the target sdk made my notifcaition visible. but for the play store, the target sdk NEEDS to be 8.0. and then it doesnt work anymore. what do i need to change here?

Comment: Why don;t you try using search to find it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel.
Refer this link..[Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Add this code before notificationManager.Notify(50, notificationBuilder.Build());

```
String channelId = "Default";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot!